# Azure Application Gateway Custom Header Rules

Tags: regex, azure, request, azure-application-gateway

We have an Azure Application Gateway setup and working. We want to add a rule that matches the following criteria for a header named X.

1. If X is not present at all in the incoming request - then let the request go through
2. If X is present but is blank or contains white-spaces - then block the request
3. If X is present but contains at least 1 non space character - then let the request go through

I used the following pattern `.+` (any character 0 of more times) - this satisfies bullet points 1 only but fails for bullet point 2 (it doesn't block the request if header is blank or has spaces) and 3 (if the header contains a non space character like `p` then request fails to go through).

[image]

What type of regular expression I need to use to satisfy all three conditions? **I was expecting `.+` to satisfy at least bullet points 1 and 3.**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-url#check-for-the-presence-of-a-header

Comment: You need `\s*\S.*` or `" *[^ ].*"` (without `"`s)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Thanks, I tried that. It is allowing absence of header (correct) but it is also allowing blank and spaces in the header and blocking the request if i add an alphabet to the header. I think the regex in application gateway work differently. I will do some experiments.

Comment: If you only allow non-whitespace, try `^\S+$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - not sure what was wrong. But for now, we went with a new ruleset for this API specifically and used the regex .+ and it does the following - missing header - blocks the request, present but empty or spaces - blocks the request, present but non-space character - lets the request goes through.

Comment: You are not giving the "regex" friendy instructions. If you need help with a regex you should say what string you need to allow/match/pass, like "A valid string must have at least 1 char, should not contain whitespaces, etc."

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - this is what the requirement is. 1. Block absence of header. 2. Don't allow blank header value. 3. Don't allow header value with only space characters. 4. Allow header with at least 1 non - space character.

Comment: Trying to translate into the "regex" requirement language: 1) String must not be empty, 2) String cannot be blank, 3) Same as #2, 4) String must contain at least one non-whitespace char. Which means something like `^\s*\S.*$` [will work](https://regex101.com/r/dhHFA9/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
^ *[^ ].*$
```

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   *                       ' ' (0 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^ ]                     any character except: ' '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```